# Sort associative array by level 4 in php

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my sample array, I would like to sort this array based on ShipPrice value which is comes on level 4 of this array, how can we do this in PHP ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ShippingTypes] => 
            [SelectedShipName] => 
            [SelectedShipId] => 
            [SelectedShipPrice] => 
            [MethodName] => UPS
            [MethodId] => 6
            [SelectedDeliveryDays] => 
            [PackageCount] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ShippingTypes] => Array
                (
                    [44] => Array
                        (
                            [ShipName] => Local pick up
                            [ShipPrice] => 12
                            [DeliveryDays] => 
                        )

                )

            [SelectedShipName] => Local pick up
            [SelectedShipPrice] => 12
            [SelectedShipId] => 44
            [MethodName] => Quantity Based
            [MethodId] => 3
            [SelectedDeliveryDays] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ShippingTypes] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ShipName] => KP Office
                            [ShipPrice] => 10
                            [DeliveryDays] => 0
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [ShipName] => Sachet
                            [ShipPrice] => 15
                            [DeliveryDays] => 5
                        )

                )

            [SelectedShipName] => KP Office
            [SelectedShipPrice] => 10
            [SelectedShipId] => 1
            [MethodName] => Local Pickup From Store
            [MethodId] => -1
            [SelectedDeliveryDays] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: `usort` them. Access till  `ShipPrice` for that.

Comment: First entry has no `ShipPrice`, how should it be sorted? And what to do with entries that have multiple `ShippingTypes` with different prices? Take the min, the max, the average?

Comment: If we do not have ShippingTypes key then we do not want to sort it, so entire [0] key was ignore from sort

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `usort` and the `max` `ShipPrice` you get for all shipping types (supposing that you actually want to check against the max):

```
usort($results, static function(array $a, array $b) {
     return price($a) <=> price($b);

});

function price(array $array): int
{
    $shippingTypes = (array) $array['ShippingTypes'];

    if (empty($shippingTypes)) {
         return 0;
    }

    return max(array_column($shippingTypes, 'ShipPrice'));
}
```